# UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning doesn't complete on iOS 9/10, but works iOS 11 and later?

Tags: swift, ios9, transition, ios11

I have a custom presentation controller which shows a UIViewController as a "bottom sheet" above the current ViewController, and allows an interactive gesture to dismiss the presented modal. The modal's `modalPresentationStyle` is set to `.current`, and the `transitioningDelegate` is set to my custom class during init(). The current code works perfectly on iOS 11 and 12, but appears to "freeze" the device on iOS 9 and 10.

Here is where the animation takes place. I have confirmed the presentedFrame and dismissedFrame are correct.

```
extension BottomSheetPresentationManager: UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {
    func transitionDuration(
        using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
        return 0.25
    }

    func interactionControllerForPresentation(using animator: UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning) -> UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning? {
        return self
    }

    func interactionControllerForDismissal(using animator: UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning) -> UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning? {
        return self
    }

    func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        let key = presenting ? UITransitionContextViewControllerKey.to
            : UITransitionContextViewControllerKey.from
        let keyV = presenting ? UITransitionContextViewKey.to
            : UITransitionContextViewKey.from

        let controller = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: key)!
        let view = transitionContext.view(forKey: keyV)!

        if presenting {
            transitionContext.containerView.addSubview(view)
        }

        let presentedFrame = transitionContext.finalFrame(for: controller)
        var dismissedFrame = presentedFrame
        switch direction {
        case .left:
            dismissedFrame.origin.x = -presentedFrame.width
        case .right:
            dismissedFrame.origin.x = transitionContext.containerView.frame.size.width
        case .top:
            dismissedFrame.origin.y = -presentedFrame.height
        case .bottom:
            dismissedFrame.origin.y = transitionContext.containerView.frame.size.height
        }

        let initialFrame = presenting ? dismissedFrame : presentedFrame
        let finalFrame = presenting ? presentedFrame : dismissedFrame

        // Runs when the animation finishes
        let completionBlock: (Bool) -> Void = { (finished) in
            // tell our transitionContext object that we've finished animating
            if transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled {
                if self.interactive {
                    transitionContext.cancelInteractiveTransition()
                }
                transitionContext.completeTransition(false)
            } else {
                if self.interactive {
                    finished ? transitionContext.finishInteractiveTransition() : transitionContext.cancelInteractiveTransition()
                }
                transitionContext.completeTransition(finished)
            }
        }

        // Put what you want to animate here.
        let animationBlock: () -> Void = {
            view.frame = finalFrame
        }

        // Set up for the animation
        let animationDuration = transitionDuration(using: transitionContext)
        view.frame = initialFrame
        // Perform a different animation based on whether we're interactive (performing a gesture) or not

        if interactive {
            // Do a linear animation so we match our dragging with our transition
            UIView.animate(withDuration: animationDuration,
                           delay: 0,
                           options: .curveLinear,
                           animations: animationBlock,
                           completion: completionBlock)

        } else {
            // Do a spring animation with easing
            UIView.animate(withDuration: animationDuration,
                           delay: 0,
                           usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8,
                           initialSpringVelocity: 0.45,
                           options: [.curveEaseInOut],
                           animations: animationBlock,
                           completion: completionBlock)
        }

    }
}
```

After much testing, I have figured out that the completion block on the UIView.animate block never gets called (completionBlock in the code), and in the Capture View Hierarchy view, it actually shows my presented view on top, with what looks like a screenshot of the view (UIVisualEffectView) directly under the presented menu.

[image: Capture View Hierarchy]

What you are seeing there is my bottom menu (the UITableView with cells that you see in front), with a UIVisualEffectView behind it (appears to be a screenshot of the UICollection view behind that), and a UICollectionView that called the present() method for the menu.

What would cause the UIView.animate block not to complete? Is there any reason the behavior would differ between iOS 10 and 11? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have the same issue. Have you managed to fix it?

Comment: @dsk1306 ended up rewriting it and it worked, not quite sure why https://github.com/ccrama/Slide-iOS/blob/master/Slide%20for%20Reddit/BottomMenuPresentationController.swift